# Silktest void 0 bug?

Tags: javascript, automation, void, silktest

I'm running some tests with Silk and it keeps throwing this error "void 0". Does anyone have any idea how I can stop this code from executing?

My platform is XP SP3, and FireFox 3.6.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Run the failing test in debug mode, stepping through until you get the error.  Once you know what is causing it, *post that* and maybe someone can help resolve the problem.

I use Silk regularly, and hearing that you're getting "void 0" with no other context is useless.